# Parsing XML document in C# with VS 2015

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to parse XML document (actually a string) by XDocument.Parse(...) method. I copied the XML code from PDF file (there are some hidden characters are embedded in the string from PDF that is complained by VS 2015). I paste the XML string to notepad and copied back to IDE editor thought the hidden characters would be removed. I enabled white space char in VS 2015, don't see anything special. I retyped the full XML string and now OK. Can anybody point me how can I detect the hidden characters easily, or is it other problem? Any tool inside VS 2015 or online? I tried some XML validator but did not help. I get the following error if I use the xmlwrong string to Parse method.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll Additional information: ' ' is an unexpected token. The
>   expected token is '?>'. Line 1, position 20.

Following XML string causes problem with Parse method (Since I copy paste again that may change the text).

```
String xmlwrong = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                    <people>
                      <person firstname=""john"" lastname=""doe"">
                        <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>john@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                        </contactdetails>
                      </person>
                      <person firstname=""jane"" lastname=""doe"">
                        <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>jane@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                          <phonenumber>001122334455</phonenumber>
                        </contactdetails>
                      </person>
                    </people>";
```

Following XML string works OK with Parse method, looks to me exactly same string.

```
        String xml =@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                   <people>
                     <person firstname=""John"" lastname=""doe"">
                       <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>john@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                       </contactdetails>
                     </person> 
                     <person firstname=""Jane"" lastname=""doe"">
                       <contactdetails>
                          <emailaddress>jane@unknown.com</emailaddress>
                           <phonenumber>001122334455</phonenumber>
                         </contactdetails>
                     </person>
                   </people>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);  //<--- causes problem
```

Comment: Normally, I would extract the pdf to a string and then save that string to a file using for example Immediate Window and a simple `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, context);`. Then I would open file in Notepad++ and select `View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters` to see the line breaks/feeds and hidden characters that Window's Notepad won't show.

Comment: It works fine here - copying and pasting the "broken" version (with `XDocument.Parse`) works fine... can you double-check the text of the failing version? Maybe there is a non-visible control character in the data?

Comment: sometimes its a quotation marks issue. Check they are 0x22

Comment: "there are some hidden characters are embedded in the string from PDF that is complained by VS 2015" then... don't do that?

Comment: This can be an idiot answer, but did you try to change the line:
version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" 

by 

version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" 
OR 
version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'

Comment: is it not simply the space between the last quote and the question mark, on the first line in the declaration of your xml doc?

Comment: @MarcGravell  how can I check non-visible control character? Before posting actually I tried most of the suggestions. I used notepadd ++, notepad etc.

Comment: @user5507337  I see most times VS studio points near the quotation marks or equal  signs

Comment: @RotatingWheel in your actual code, is it coming from a file? or from a string literal? If it is a string literal: loop over the string and output the code-points (`(int)c`); if it is a file: loop over the *bytes* and do the same. Check that everything is in the 32-126 range (or: 9=tab, 10=lf, 13=cr)